# How to add buttons into a jtoolbar dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I have a java application which requires to add button sets contains in jpanels dynamically.
ex:-

```
.
.

JButton button1 = new JButton("Button_1");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Button_2");

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button1);
tblMainToolBar.add(panel);

.
.
```

above code adds the panel into the tool bar but, to see the added panel I have to minimize or maximize the main window. please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding components to a visible GUI the code should be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call yourFrame.[pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) after `.add()` .